# Fluid configuration doubt

Tags: fluid-dynamics, fluid-statics

[image]

I just wanted to enquire, can this system ever be possible for ideal fluid.

I strongly believe it can't be possible since, there has been no increase in the cross section, but still the pressure difference has increased between the points, indicating a change in velocity which would ultimately flout the equation of continuity.

One more thing, can viscous fluid ever achieve this configuration?

P.S. the fluid is same everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

*By definition* an ideal liquid is [inviscid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inviscid_flow). An *inviscid fluid* flows through a pipe without any pressure losses because there are no viscous (friction) energy losses.

In your figure the pipe $L,L,L$ is perfectly horizontal, so there are no changes in potential energy either.

In that situation, for an ideal liquid, the levels in the manometers would all be identical.

> One more thing, can viscous fluid ever achieve this configuration?

For a viscous, Newtonian liquid in steady flow pressure loss is directly proportional to pipe length (for a pipe of constant cross section). That would yield the pattern shown in your figure. See [Darcy-Weisbach equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darcy%E2%80%93Weisbach_equation#Laminar_regime).

Comment: It would also be true for steady turbulent flow.

Comment: You're right: it's only the friction coefficient that differs. It's been edited, thanks.

Comment: But if I measure $h_i \rho g$ ${i=1,2,3}$ that would yield different pressures beneath $h_i$. Won't that make my system go wrong?

Comment: I know that whenever a fluid (non-viscuous) passes through tube of same crossection, there is no change in kinetic energy that's why no change in pressure (assuming the tube to be horizontal) but when we apply the$ h_i \rho g$  at subsequent points L, there is actually a decrease in pressure. How is that possible?

Comment: @Harsh Sharma It won't make your system go wrong.  There is no flow in those vertical tubes, so it merely represents a hydrostatic measurement of the pressure at the three locations.  It's the same as if you put a pressure transducer in the wall of the tube at those locations.

Comment: @ChesterMiller you mean to say that I am actually measuring the hydrostatic pressure there which is of no use in a dynamics system?

Comment: @HarshSharma Yes.  You're actually measuring the local pressure in the pipe hydrostatically.  I don't know if I could generalize this to all flow systems, but in this system, the vertical columns of fluid in the tubes have negligible effect of the pressure and flow distribution in the pipe.

Comment: @ChesterMiller you have now given me a one more doubt. Can't I use hydrostatic pressure using the depth of point from free surface in hydrodynamics system? for example if a fluid is moving with velocity v and point is there at a depth h from the free surface. What would be its pressure?Won't it be $\rho h g$

Comment: @HarshSharma As I said earlier, if there is no flow in the vertical tubes (which there won't be), then the pressures at the bases of the three vertical tubes will be $\rho gh$, and will match the pressure of the flowing fluid in the pipe.  The fluid in the vertical tubes is "passive" and doesn't contribute to the pressure variation in the pipe.  The columns in the tubes are the effect, not the cause.